# Extract vertical and horizontal dimensions of an irregular object

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, pattern-matching, dimensions

I have the following object and want to extract the maximum vertical (red line) and horizontal (blue line) sizes in MATLAB.

[image]

I used the following code, but I am not sure if I am using a right property:

```
L = bwlabel(myImage);
prop = regionprops(L,'BoundingBox');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want another answer that doesn't use `regionprops`, assuming that the black mass is the **only** object in the image, you can find the minimum spanning bounding box by finding the top left and bottom right corners of the object, then finding the width and height by subtracting the right-most column and left-most column and bottom most-row and top-most row of whatever is considered an object pixel respectively.  Assuming your binary image is stored in `L`, do the following:

```
[r,c] = find(~L);
width = max(c) - min(c) + 1;
height = max(r) - min(r) + 1;
```

[`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) finds all row and column locations that are non-zero.  As such, I had to **invert** your image so that all zero locations become non-zero.  `r` and `c` are column vectors that return the row and column locations of what is non-zero respectively then the logic I stated above is carried out.

Answer (score 2):

If you literally just want the *sizes* of those lines, they are the already contained in the result from `regionprops`.

```
prop = regionprops(L, 'BoundingBox');

prop = 

    BoundingBox: [x, y, width, height]
```

The lengths of your blue and red lines will be the third and fourth elements of the `BoundingBox` field, respectively.

Comment: My image is the left one and I just demonstrated what I want on the right one. So, can I find the those sizes using the "BoundingBox" on the left image?

Comment: @Sam: *"The lengths of your blue and red lines will be the third and fourth elements of the `BoundingBox` field, respectively."*  I don't think there is any room for misinterpretation in that statement. It's clearly spelled out.